# R | Fisher test error is saying out of workspace?

Tags: r, excel, math, statistics, chi-squared

I'm trying to compare two columns for significant association and thus am using a Fisher test as most cell values are 0. The first thing I did was create a 2x2 contingency table, but it is not correct, and am not sure what's why it won't create the contingency table. How can this be fixed?

ERROR:

```
> fisher.test(data_table)
Error in fisher.test(data_table) : FEXACT error 40.
Out of workspace.
```

CODE:

```
#import Excel file into R
setwd('C:\\Users\\main\\Desktop')
data <- read.csv("Framingham.csv")

diabetes_no <- subset(xx,DIABETES==0)$DIABETES
diabetes_yes <- subset(xx,DIABETES==1)$DIABETES
cursmoke_no <- subset(xx,CURSMOKE==0)$CURSMOKE
cursmoke_yes <- subset(xx,CURSMOKE==1)$CURSMOKE
# create 2x2 table
data_table = matrix(c(diabetes_no,diabetes_yes,cursmoke_no,cursmoke_yes), nrow = 2)
data_table
fisher.test(data_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you should turn data into a 2x2 contingency table to use a `chisq.test`. Check out [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555832/testing-if-one-binary-variable-is-related-to-another-binary-variable) for details. Here's a **trivial** example of how you could do this (note that the dataset here is too small to have a meaningful result, so `chisq.test` will give a warning):

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~col1, ~col2,
  0, 1,
  1, 1,
  0, 0,
  1, 1,
  1, 1,
  1, 1,
  1, 1,
  0, 1,
  0, 1,
  0, 1,
  0, 1,
  0, 1, 
  0, 1
)

a <- df %>% filter(col1 == 0 & col2 == 0) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% pull(n)
b <- df %>% filter(col1 == 1 & col2 == 0) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% pull(n)
c <- df %>% filter(col1 == 0 & col2 == 1) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% pull(n)
d <- df %>% filter(col1 == 1 & col2 == 1) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% pull(n)

contingency_table <- data.frame(col1_0 = c(a, c), col1_1 = c(b, d), row.names = c("col2_0", "col2_1"))

contingency_table
#>        col1_0 col1_1
#> col2_0      1      0
#> col2_1      7      5

chisq.test(contingency_table)

#>  Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates'
#>  continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  contingency_table
#> X-squared = 7.7448e-32, df = 1, p-value = 1
```

Comment: This might not tell the full story - `chisq.test(df$col1, df$col2)` will work, as will `chisq.test(table(df))` - both with the same result AFAIK.